# Something something: and the Scourge of (Rykard?)

Tags: story-identification

I had a wonderful fantasy book, which was part of a series, in the mid '90s. On the cover was a man that looked like Kratos from God of War.  In the story, he at one point got a gem shoved into his chest by an old wizard that was giving him powers and glowing.  WTF is this book?  I can't find it ANYWHERE on the internet.  HELP!

Comment: Welcome to Sci-Fi & Fantasy Stack Exchange!  There is a helpful post [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/656) which could help you to provide more details so we can assist you in finding the story you're looking for.  Take a look, and use the 'Edit' link on your question to provide more detail!

Comment: [This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161918/fantasy-novel-where-characters-have-gemstones-implanted-in-their-bodies-female) question seems similar in many ways, perhaps looking at the answers it provides will help?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't read the book you are referencing, but a bit of Googling points me towards the [Dark Sun series](http://darksun.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Novel).

One of the books in the series, [The Crimson Legion](http://darksun.wikia.com/wiki/The_Crimson_Legion), features a fairly God-of-War-esque character on the cover.

[image: Could this be the book?]

The Dark Sun series features a sword known as the [Scourge of Rkard](http://darksun.wikia.com/wiki/Scourge_of_Rkard), so named because the sword (previously known just as the 'Scourge') was used to kill a character named Rkard.

There's no information I could find quickly about a character gaining powers by having a gem pressed into their chest, but that is a fairly common trope of the genre, so it seems possible.

Comment: WOW!  Exactly.  You're amazing.  I'm gonna go ahead and read the whole series again and pretend I'm in 5th grade again.  Thank you!

Comment: @user89829 - Glad I could help!  Please remember that if an answer has helped you, you can upvote it using the arrows to the left, and if it is the solution, you can use the check mark to accept it.