# Fantasy book series where the rulers of the city have gemstones in their chests

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I've been trying to find this series for years and hoping someone has some insight. This was a YA fantasy series that I read in the mid-90's about a city that was ruled by four couples. Each couple had a signature gemstone (emerald, ruby, diamond, etc) in their chest and that signified which group they were a part of. There were some sex scenes, and I remember them joining their gemstones together would renew their powers. The children had to go to a temple for their coming-of-age ceremony, and they had to communicate with some large powerful stone. In my mind they called it a heart stone, but that may not be accurate. They had to undergo a series of tests to become rulers. This is as much as I can remember, I don't have a mental image of the cover. I'd like to read it again if I can find it. Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Some similar stories are mentioned in these unaccepted answers, do any seem familiar? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161918/fantasy-novel-where-characters-have-gemstones-implanted-in-their-bodies-female

Comment: Nope, I read through that thread before I posted my question. Although powerful jewels do seem to be a common theme!